# PHPMailer 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I have a form with AJAX,PHP. Sometimes when I want to send an email I get this error "500 Internal Server Error" I don't know what to do. Here is my code

HTML:

```
            <form id="myForm" method="post" class="result" >

                <input class="input-style" type="email" required name="email" placeholder=" E-mail"><br>
                <br>
                <input class="input-style" type="text" required name="subject" placeholder=" Subject">
                <br><br/>
                <textarea class="input-style" rows="5" required cols="100" name="message" placeholder=" Message"></textarea>
                <input style="text-align:center;" id="sumbitBtn" class="submit-button" type="submit" name='submit-mail' value="SEND">   
            </form>



        </div>
    </div>




</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function ()
        {

            //var fn = $("#fname").val();
            //var ln = $("#lname").val();

            //var data = 'fname='+fn+'&lname='+ln;

            var data = $(this).serialize();


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../db/contact.php',
                data: data,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $("#myForm").fadeOut(500).hide(function ()
                    {
                        $(".result").fadeIn(500).show(function ()
                        {
                            $(".result").html(data);
                        });
                    });

                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Here is my PHP part with PHPMailer

```
require '../plugins/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subiect = $_POST['subiect'];
$body = $_POST['mesaj'];

//var_dump($email);
//var_dump($subiect);
//var_dump($body);
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "myhost";
$mail->Username = "email@ema.com";
$mail->Password = "pass#";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = "587";


$mail->AddAddress('myemail', 'receivers');
$mail->setFrom($email, $email);
$mail->Subject = $subiect;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $body;

if ($mail->Send()) {
//    echo "Message was Successfully Send :)";
}
?>

<form id='myForm' class='result' >

    <input class='input-style' type='email' required name='email' placeholder=' E-mail'><br>
    <br>
    <input class='input-style' type='text' required name='subject' placeholder=' Subject'>
    <br><br/>
    <textarea class='input-style' rows='5' required cols='100' name='message' placeholder=' mess'></textarea>
    <!--    <div id='icon-confirm'>
            <input style='text-align:center;' id='sumbitBtn' class='submit-button-sent' type='submit' name='submit-mail' value='SENT'>
        </div>-->

    <div class='input-group'>
        <span class='input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-confirm' id='basic-addon1' style='color:#ffcc02 !important;background-color:transparent !important;'></span>
        <input type='button' class='form-control' value='Trimis' aria-describedby='basic-addon1'>
    </div>

</form>
```

I've tried to make change in code but no solution. What can I do to solve the problem? I think is from AJAX part

Comment: in what page do you get the error?

Comment: errno 500 is a server error, i think, that you cant access url, do you have any .htaccess rules or rights permisions on your file?

Comment: Comes from PHP part with phpmailer

Comment: I have rules in .htaccess but not for this file

Comment: Check your error logs and / or  up your [error_reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting) / enable `display_errors`

Comment: No errors shows..it's so strange, because sometimes my email is sent, other times I have this error

Comment: I guess the errror comes from passing PHP data